# KafkaConsumer to SQLite to streamlit or visualization Problem

Tags: python, sqlite, apache-kafka, real-time, streamlit

I have a project in which I have a KafkaConsumer and I an storing the stream data in SQLite
Also I have a thread running to SELECT from SQLite per 5 seconds and visualizing using streamlit
Firstly when the TABLE size was less it work well, but when the TABLE row exceeded appx. 20000 rows
The INSERT operation got crash

```
conn.executemany(self.insert_statement(num_rows=1), data_list)
sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked
```

CODE for INSERT from KakfaConsumer

```
# Create a connection to the SQLite database
conn = sqlite3.connect('extracted_stream_data.db', isolation_level=None, timeout=0.01)
print(conn)
# Create a Kafka consumer
consumer_2 = KafkaConsumer('extracted_data',
                           value_deserializer=lambda m: m.decode('utf8'),
                           bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'],
                           auto_offset_reset='latest')

def store_extracted_data_to_db():
    print('processor 4')
    # Continuously consume and store streaming data
    for message in consumer_2:
        if message is None:
            continue

        # Decode the message value and convert it to a DataFrame
        value = message.value
        df = pd.DataFrame.from_records([json.loads(value)])
        df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], unit='ms')
        # Append the data to the SQLite database table
        df.to_sql('extracted_stream_data', conn, if_exists='append', index=False)
    # Close the database connection and Kafka consumer
    conn.close()
    consumer_2.close()


store_extracted_data_to_db()
```

LOGIC 1

```
def visualize():
    conn = connect_to_database(EXTRACTED_DATABASE_FILE)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT timestamp, sum(freq) AS request_per_second FROM extracted_stream_data GROUP BY    
                     timestamp ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1')
    request_per_second = cursor.fetchall()
    # Top row ( count and per second requests)
    t1, t2, t3 = st.columns(3)
    # st.write(request_per_second)
    t1.write(f'##### Current Time {request_per_second[0][0]}')
    t2.write('##### Request per seconds : ' + str(request_per_second[0][1]))
    
    # Other Operations also
    conn.close()
```

This give ERROR

```
conn.executemany(self.insert_statement(num_rows=1), data_list)
sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked
```

LOGIC 2
This is a alternate approach I though about

```
TOPIC = 'extracted_data'
# connecting consumer
consumer = KafkaConsumer(bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'],
                         value_deserializer=lambda x: x.decode('utf-8'))
# checking all topics available to consume
print('topics available')
print(consumer.topics())
# selecting topic 'extracted_data'
consumer.subscribe(TOPIC)

print(consumer.partitions_for_topic(TOPIC))
ph = st.empty()
buffer = []
count = 0
last_timestamp = None
for consumer_record in consumer:
    message = json.loads(consumer_record.value)
    # print(json.loads(message)['timestamp'],message)
    if last_timestamp is None:
        last_timestamp = message['timestamp']
    if message['timestamp'] - last_timestamp >= 3000:
        print(pd.to_datetime(last_timestamp, unit='ms').strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
        # process(window_df)
        print(len(buffer))
        with ph.container():
            st.write(pd.to_datetime(last_timestamp, unit='ms').strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), len(buffer))
            # time.sleep(20)
            # TODO
        last_timestamp = message['timestamp']
        buffer = []
    else:
        buffer.append(message)
```

This logic is having making problem as it create multiple thread at `with st.container()`

Should I stop using this LOGIC 1 or there is any solution for selecting and inserting parallel.

Any other suggestions will be appreciated